# Is this PHP Code Efficient?

Tags: php, wordpress, performance, switch-statement

This seems like a common question, but with all sorts of different answers, so here goes. I'm helping someone build a wordpress site and I made a switch statement to check which category page the user was on to show a picture and a description. I also wrote a very simple function to see if the category has any posts in order to display a message.

**To better explain the code:**
This bit of code at the top uses a few Wordpress functions and objects (to my understanding) to grab the Category Slug of the current page:

```
$cat = get_category( get_query_var( 'cat' ) );
    $cat_id = $cat->cat_ID;
    $cat_name = $cat->name;
    $cat_slug = $cat->slug;
```

I renamed all of the pictures to the same name as the category slug to reuse the same variable for all of the statements.

The next bit of code sees whether or not the page has any posts:

```
function add_page_title_header( ){
        function check_if_posts(){
            if(!have_posts()){
                echo '<span id="stillworking">There currently isn\'t any content for this category, but there will be soon. For now try another!</span>';
            }
        }
```

The rest of the code (embedded below, the switch statement) uses the Category slug it got from the page to input the picture and then the hard-coded description. (After explaining it this way, I realize that by using the same variable over again I don't need a switch statement for each of them, I'll address that in the answers below)

```
$cat = get_category( get_query_var( 'cat' ) );
$cat_id = $cat->cat_ID;
$cat_name = $cat->name;
$cat_slug = $cat->slug;
switch ($cat_slug) {
    case 'ultracarnivorous':
        echo '<span id="titlecenter"><img src="'. home_url() . '/images/big/' . $cat_slug . '.png"></span>';
        echo '<span id="catdescription">A puppet show starring cryptids.</span>';
        check_if_posts();
        break;
    case 'things-of-interest':
        echo '<span id="titlecenter"><img src="'. home_url() . '/images/big/' . $cat_slug . '.png"></span>';
        echo '<span id="catdescription">Interesting things of all kinds.</span>';
        check_if_posts();
        break;
    case 'tim-and-james':
        echo '<span id="titlecenter"><img src="'. home_url() . '/images/big/' . $cat_slug . '.png"></span>';
        echo '<span id="catdescription">Editorial posts by Tim and James, the website\'s creators.</span>';
        check_if_posts();
        break;
    case 'the-tin-age-of-comics':
        echo '<span id="titlecenter"><img src="'. home_url() . '/images/big/' . $cat_slug . '.png"></span>';
        echo '<span id="catdescription">A web comic using royalty free comic book art.</span>';
        check_if_posts();
        break;
    case 'chainsaw-podcast':
        echo '<span id="titlecenter"><img src="'. home_url() . '/images/big/' . $cat_slug . '.png"></span>';
        echo '<span id="catdescription">A podcast by Tim and James, the website\'s creators.</span>';
        check_if_posts();
        break;
    case 'songink':
        echo '<span id="titlecenter"><img src="'. home_url() . '/images/big/' . $cat_slug . '.png"></span>';
        echo '<span id="catdescription">Short stories inspired by songs.</span>';
        check_if_posts();
        break;
    case 'takeaways':
        echo '<span id="titlecenter"><img src="'. home_url() . '/images/big/' . $cat_slug . '.png"></span>';
        echo '<span id="catdescription">A short, accessible thing to do this week.</span>';
        check_if_posts();
        break;
    case 'chainsaw-gaming':
        echo '<span id="titlecenter"><img src="'. home_url() . '/images/big/' . $cat_slug . '.png"></span>';
        echo '<span id="catdescription">Playing, reviewing and inventing games of all kinds.</span>';
        check_if_posts();
        break;
    case 'chainsaw-radio-theatre':
        echo '<span id="titlecenter"><img src="'. home_url() . '/images/big/' . $cat_slug . '.png"></span>';
        echo '<span id="catdescription">A fake, old-timey radio show full of factoids.</span>';
        check_if_posts();
        break;
    case 'canonically-incorrect':
        echo '<span id="titlecenter"><img src="'. home_url() . '/images/big/' . $cat_slug . '.png"></span>';
        echo '<span id="catdescription">Posts by our lovable friend, Jason.</span>';
        check_if_posts();
        break;
    case 'chainsaw-phraseology':
        echo '<span id="titlecenter"><img src="'. home_url() . '/images/big/' . $cat_slug . '.png"></span>';
        echo '<span id="catdescription">Fun with words and language.</span>';
        check_if_posts();
        break;
    case 'chicken-fried-awesome':
        echo '<span id="titlecenter"><img src="'. home_url() . '/images/big/' . $cat_slug . '.png"></span>';
        echo '<span id="catdescription">Food reviews with a twist.</span>';
        check_if_posts();
        break;
    case 'transmission-received':
        echo '<span id="titlecenter"><img src="'. home_url() . '/images/big/' . $cat_slug . '.png"></span>';
        echo '<span id="catdescription">A daily, back and forth video conversation.</span>';
        check_if_posts();
    break;
    case 'link-burger':
        echo '<span id="titlecenter"><img src="'. home_url() . '/images/big/' . $cat_slug . '.png"></span>';
        echo '<span id="catdescription">A group of links to enjoy in one sitting.</span>';
        check_if_posts();
        break;
    case 'chainsaw-reviews':
        echo '<span id="titlecenter"><img src="'. home_url() . '/images/big/' . $cat_slug . '.png"></span>';
        echo '<span id="catdescription">Reviews of all kinds by the website\'s creators.</span>';
        check_if_posts();
        break;
    case 'multifarious-machinations':
        echo '<span id="titlecenter"><img src="'. home_url() . '/images/big/' . $cat_slug . '.png"></span>';
        echo '<span id="catdescription">A catch-all category for posts that don\'t seem to fit anywhere else.</span>';
        check_if_posts();
        break;



    default:
    echo "This is awkward, you shouldn't be seeing this page!";
}
    }

    add_filter( 'thematic_page_title', 'add_page_title_header' );
```

If you see any obvious mistakes or memory-hog type things, let me know. I also plan to leverage browser caching when the site is all finished, is it possible the function I wrote will create a problem with this? Usually when a post is published it resets certain cache elements but will this function only run again once the cache is cleared? Is there a way to avoid this?

I've used this site in the past countless times, but this marks my first question, so hooray for that.

You can see it in (albeit beta) action by visiting http://chainsawcreative.com and clicking any of the categories on the left. As soon as the design is finished, other optimizations will come into play, but I'm only concerned with this particular bit of PHP for now.

Comment: Can't you better address the question by describing what that code does instead of providing 100 lines of spaghetti code..? I am not trying to be offensive.. Just an advice if you really need help make it easy for others to help you.

Comment: No it isn't efficient.... the only differences in all the case blocks are the actual description, so stick the descriptions in an array indexed by `$cat_slug` and just use an isset to test and then get the description from the array so that you only have one set of echo/check_if_posts().

Comment: I'll edit the question to better explain it.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it would be better suited to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Sorry about that, I wasn't entirely sure where to put it. I'll keep that in mind for next time, thank you.

Comment: Performance in a PHP based website can be a worry only if it is **very** high volume...

Comment: That is also very good to know, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can load the description from the database like you are for the other fields, that'd be simplest. Otherwise, if you need to hard-code the descriptions, and your output will always be identical except for the description text, it's simpler to have an array storing the description texts, and then not duplicate the identical output code.

E.g.

```
$descriptions = array(
   'ultracarnivorous'   =>  "A puppet show starring cryptids.",
   'things-of-interest' =>  "Interesting things of all kinds.",
   'tim-and-james'      =>  "Editorial posts by Tim and James, the website's creators."
);
echo '<span id="titlecenter"><img src="'. home_url() . '/images/big/' . $cat_slug . '.png"></span>';
echo '<span id="catdescription">' . htmlspecialchars($descriptions[$cat_slug]) . '</span>';
check_if_posts();
```

Comment: This is exactly the sort of thing I was looking for, thank you. The descriptions aren't (currently) anywhere in the database so the array option seems like the best one.